# When i make request to googleapis, getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-api, bad-request, google-developers-console, google-groups, google-groups-api

I am trying to get the list of groups (distribution lists) for a specific user. It is getting failed.

Request is

```
`GET /admin/directory/v1/groups HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer ya29.Il-9B-9Z88RKqK73dr-NyeeJnCz0PqlPrMgxlr0JO6gc2q2jcROxsu7y6EaTHAlRkJatv5l3kd_PIPHrB7wXeMvfe0YTXupzupJ8-PUyrRcCIBE_qpPP8V7NoM0JJp`
```

But the I am getting the error response shown below.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400, 
        "message": "Bad Request", 
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global", 
                "message": "Bad Request", 
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Not only when getting groups but every API call from googleapis.com is behaving like this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error/confusion about usage of some of the google apis.

I'm assuming you're using a service account with domain-wide delegation access rights?

Assuming yes, the issue is that in addition to the service account credentials, you need to set a user that the google credentials will `impersonate` when making the request.  That is, the domain wide delegation only allows you to act as though you are one of the actual users, on my understanding.

I couldn't see any way to set this via google base api, other than using the builder directly.  Here is a sample:

```java
  static GoogleCredential createCredential(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory) throws Exception {
    final String credentialJsonPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.config/gcloud/service-cred-from-console.json";
    try (InputStream credentialStream = new FileInputStream(credentialJsonPath)) {
      final GoogleCredential firstPassCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialStream, transport, jsonFactory);

      return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setTransport(transport)
          .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
          .setServiceAccountId(firstPassCred.getServiceAccountId())
          .setServiceAccountProjectId(firstPassCred.getServiceAccountProjectId())
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(firstPassCred.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyId(firstPassCred.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())
          // service accounts must act on behalf of an actual user and have scope
          .setServiceAccountScopes(Lists.newArrayList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE, GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_SHARING))
          .setServiceAccountUser("a.real.gsuite.account@example.com")
          .build();
    }
  }
```

The important parts are defining the `ServiceAccountUser` (who you impersonate) and the `ServiceAccountScope(s)` you are assuming for that user.

I posted an [example gmail api gist](https://gist.github.com/tom-haines/3ec0c4535f247922c270254322b64a6a).  You could run this through a local proxy like `charles` (et al) if you want the equiv. REST call sequence.